# Higher Resolution Xrandr 1400x1050 Legacy GPU

Tags: nvidia, xorg, resolution, lightdm, xrandr

Dear Ubuntu Community,

recently I (re)found my 10 year old Sony Vaio laptop, a PCG-GRT916V to be exact. I immediately had the idea to put this old laptop to good use. Over the course of two weeks I installed a few lightweight Ubuntu (14.04 LTS) flavours (nm. Lubuntu, Xubuntu and lastly the all new Ubuntu Mate). Just to verify what will and what will not work on such old hardware. Everything still works great as it should. There's only one thing for which I have not been able to find a solution. Namely to get the screen to work at full resolution: 1400x1050 instead of 10124x768.

I've been looking for all kinds of things, sadly nothing works. The xrandr approach was the first one I tried out. The Ubuntu wiki explains it in (some) detail:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

It looked quite easy at first glance; cvt, newmode, addmode, etc. But nope, it didn't work at all.

```
"Xrandr: failed to get size of gamma for output default"
```

At the first try, working with xrandr, I ignored the error. Installed the program ARandR, rebooted and tried setting a higher resolution. Of course it didn't work.

Looking for this kind of error, I came across a lot of answers and solutions. Apparently there's quite some problems with setting up a higher resolution. But then again no luck or even a work around for my particular problem. I sincerely hope someone amongst you does know some sort of solution, at least some advise to push me in the right direction.

Below some info listed

Info about the GPU

```
lspci -nn | grep -i vga
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation NV31M [GeForce FX Go5600] [10de:031a] (rev a1)
```

Let's give xrandr a try

```
xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       61.0* 
   800x600        61.0  
   640x480        60.0
```

Please note the error (failed ... output) and that the laptop screen is recognized as "default"

```
cvt 1400 1050
# 1400x1050 59.98 Hz (CVT 1.47M3) hsync: 65.32 kHz; pclk: 121.75 MHz
Modeline "1400x1050_60.00"  121.75  1400 1488 1632 1864  1050 1053 1057 1089 -hsync +vsync
```

Let's try adding the new mode/ resolution anyway

```
xrandr --newmode "1400x1050_60.00"  121.75  1400 1488 1632 1864  1050 1053 1057 1089 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default

xrandr --addmode default 1400x1050_60.00
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

Let us check if the new mode/ resolution 1400x1050 has been added

```
xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1400 x 1050
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       61.0* 
   800x600        61.0  
   640x480        60.0  
   1400x1050_60.00   60.0
```

It looks like it is actually added. Now let us try to make it the "default mode"

```
xrandr --output default --mode 1400x1050_60.00
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

Please note the second error: "Configure crtc 0 failed"

After a reboot there, sadly enough, there's no change in the resolution. Using the Screen Layout Editor ARandR, the newly added resolution can actually be found under outputs - defaults -resolution - 1400x105060.00

When I tried applying this resolution through ARandR, it returned an error:

```
XRandR failed:
XRandR returned error code 1: xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

Here's where I got stuck, no matter what kind of solution or work around I used following the advice others where given in fora scattered over the internet.

Was I looking in the wrong place? Lies the solution in making/ editing a Xorg.conf file (as I understood)? When looking up Xorg.conf and NVIDIA Corporation NV31M I stumbled upon the following site:

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2005-December/061097.html

Is this a good example of how to set a Xorg.conf file up? What about Lightdm? Does someone know how to tackle this dilemma? Any advice or direct help is greatly appreciated.

> See it as a challenge. Thank you in advance!